# ajaxSuccess event firing sequence

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

as a debugging/learning tool I insert this into my code:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    console.log('ajax complete');
});
```

I want to see where ajax gets its answer related to other events using `console.log()`.

So I have:

```
function place_confirm (place_name,place_code) {
    console.log('into place_confirm');
    var place_confirm_html= '<p>confermi da '+place_name+ '?</p>';
    //here the function does other stuff
}

$.post('./shyne/ajax/approve.php', {place_code:place_code}, function (data){
    if (data == '_no_'){$('.error').html('il codice non è corretto');
    } else {
        place_confirm(data,place_code);
}
```

The strange thing to me is that the console.log writes:

*into place confirm*

*ajax complete*

while I thought it had to be the inverse: after *ajax complete* I have my function associated in *success* run.

So I have two questions:

1. does the console give a good representation of the sequence of events happening?
2. which is the right ajax event to attach a function I want to be executed only after Ajax got its response?

Comment: `place_confirm` function is called before `ajaxSuccess` handler since `place_confirm` call is within context `success` event handler which has higher priority than `ajaxSuccess` handler. I.e. each context `success` event handler is called before any handler registered with `ajaxSuccess`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function place_confirm will be triggered before the ajaxSuccess because the Ajax call is async. So while the JavaScrpt file is waiting for the Ajax Response it will perform other functions. That's why the function will be executed first.

If you want that the ajaxSuccess function will be executed first you need to set the async to false like below:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    ....
})
.done(function(response){
    //Some Logic here if the Ajax succeded     
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert('Error : ' + errorThrown); // error handling
});
```

But notice: If you set async to false Javascript MUST NOT perform other code until the AjaxResponse arrived! It will work like a singlethreated programming language!

Btw the code above is the new way to handle Ajax Calls correctly, the old way with Success und Error is deprecated in newer Versions, just for your information :)

The console can give you good information, but it only does so much. The console.log() can't give you information about WHY the functions are called in the order they are executed, but you'll see that they ARE executed in the order. The reason for that behaivior is explained in the first sentence, if you want further information just ask. :)

Sorry for possible bad grammar!

EDIT:

Welcome to stack overflow :)

Comment: your advice worked perfectly. Sorry that I can't vote at the moment. How can I see WHY the functions are called in the order they are executed?

Comment: No Problem, but you can accept the answer, you should see a symbol for that beneath the Arrows to vote, just as advice :) You could debug the JavaScript with Firebug, setting an Breakpoint in your code and then work through your code step by step. Maybe things will be clearer then. Else i could only say that it is pretty much the understandig of the eventdriven style of JavaScript. Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I know the `$.post` function takes these parameters `(URL, dataToPass, successFunction)`. So what you're doing is calling place_confirm function on success which will be called first before the other ajaxSuccess function you used. So to answer your questions:
1. Yes the sequence is correct.
2. You could use the `done()` event.

```
$.post('./shyne/ajax/approve.php', {place_code:place_code})
   .done( function (data){
      if (data == '_no_'){
         $('.error').html('il codice non è corretto');
      } else {
         place_confirm(data,place_code);
      }
   })
```

Comment: I tested with *done* but I get the same order as before: first 'into place_confirm'
then
'ajax complete' from the console.log(); I want to get the opposite

Comment: Forgot to mention that you do not need the `ajaxSuccess` function anymore. Use the `done` function to do whatever you want after ajax returns data